# wordpress is not decoding uniocde received from android app

Tags: android, json, wordpress, utf8-decode

We are using a premium wordpress theme for our hindi news site. We have cretaed an android app to allow anyone news publish from mobile. When someone publish hindi news from mobile app. fonts in unicode comes to database. In mobile app, we can see news in proper hindi font but on site they do not get decoded and shows like" ???%E0" etc.

Can anyone help me in decoding in wordpress. [My site](http://bhuchal.in)